# Python: find maximum x-value and maximum y-value in text file

Tags: python, max, polygon, point, min

i have question about finding maximum x or y-value in text file. This is necessary for point in polygon algorithm.
Polygons are entered in text file together with point, that is in or out polygon and together with number of lines of polygon.

For example:

```
5.0 4.0 6 1.0 1.0 4.0 0.0 6.0 3.0 7.0 6.0 3.0 7.0 0.0 4.0 1.0 1.0
```

The point is `[5.0 4.0]`, polygon has `6` lines and next are written points of polygon:

```
[1.0 1.0][4.0 0.0][6.0 3.0][7.0 6.0][3.0 7.0][0.0 4.0][1.0 1.0].
```

First is x-coordinate, second is y-coordinate.

I have procedure that tests the position of 2 lines. Now I have to combine this procedure with this one algorithm.

What i have is:open txt a read line of txt, then split it and save the values to variables

```
pointinp = open ("pointinp.txt", "r")  
for line in pointinp.readlines():  
    riadok = line.split()  
    j=3  
    for i in range (0,riadok[2]):  
        x1=float(riadok[0])  
        y1=float(riadok[1])  
        k1=float(riadok[i+j])  
        l1=float(riadok[i+(j+1)])  
        k2=float(riadok[i+(j+2)])  
        l2=float(riadok[i+(j+3)])  
        j=j+1
```

Point coordinates is in x1 and y1, coordinates of other points are in k1,l1,k2,l2. Now i have to find maximum x and y coordinate from text file to save it to x2,y2.
So then I will have 2 lines [x1,y1][x2,y2] and [k1,l1][k2,l2] and then i will test position of these lines and this is necessary in point in polygon algorithm, where will be counted the intersection points.(intersection between created line containing point and each line of polygon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Findind the maximum x and y in the *line* is straightforward enough, you just need to be able to separate them out and apply the max() function to them. Fortunately python list indexing supports a step size, so you can easily pull out every other value:

```
xvals=riadok[3::2]
yvals=riadok[4::2]
xmax=max(xvals)
ymax=max(yvals)
```

Finding the maximum in the *file* is a bit harder: for each line you can compare your local maximum to the largest figure found so far, and replace the latter with the former if it is greater:

```
xtruemax=max(xtruemax,xmax)
ytruemax=max(ytruemax,ymax)
```

but you will find these figures slowly growing as you go further through your file. If you want the genuine largest value of x and y available right from line one then you will have to process your file in two passes, once to find the maximum x and y and once to apply your algorithm.

Comment: I dont know if I understood it enough. Exactly, I understand principle of it, but dont know how do it - find local maximum in file and compare it. How will code look like? It will compare with all values (so x will be compared with y), or?

Comment: using the same examples as before: 
`for line in pointinp.readlines():
    riadok=line.split()
    xvals=riadok[3::2]
    yvals=riadok[4::2] 
    xmax=max(xvals)
    ymax=max(yvals)
    xtruemax=max(xtruemax,xmax)
    ytruemax=max(ytruemax,ymax)
pointinp.seek(0)
for line in pointinp.readlines():
    <your code here>'
wether you compare xmax to x and y or just y depends on the nature of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you like powerfull code you would like this :)
If you just have integer numbers you can substitute float by int.

file.txt

1 2 3 900000.029384 10000 6 8 900000.029383

> maximum= max(map(float,(open('file.txt', 'r').readline()).split()))